# libjpeg API and Reference

Tags: c, libjpeg

I am having trouble finding an API that details functions calls and return values... The headers aren't exactly very clean either...

I have found tons of examples, but I'm interested in error handling (return values). Am I approaching this wrong because I'm tearing my hair out trying to find something as basic as a function list for this well known library.

Comment: [Error handling in libjpeg](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19857766/86967)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This question is 7 years old now, and the `libjpeg` project has become stagnant.  However, the `libjpeg-turbo` project appears to be its successor, and it is backwards-compatible with the old `libjpeg` API.

There is some documentation in [libjpeg.txt](https://github.com/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo/blob/master/libjpeg.txt).
libjpeg is a very low-level, steep-learning-curve, old school c library.  To use it effectively you need to be familiar with setjmp and longjmp, c structure layouts, function pointers, and lots of other low-level C stuff.  It's a bear to work with but possible to do a great deal with minimal resource usage.

The documentation is not that great.  I think the authors intended that anybody using this library would be able to read through the source and figure out how the stuff works.

Comment: Also, at the top of this file, it makes mention of the heavy commented https://github.com/Windower/libjpeg/blob/master/example.c file.

Comment: Links are dead. I think you have to download the `.tar.gz` or `.zip` file listed at https://www.ijg.org/ and then find that file there. I haven't tried it though.

Comment: The legacy libjpeg API example is now in https://github.com/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo/blob/master/example.txt .  I think they're trying to steer people towards their simpler newer API.

Comment: As far as as I understand, libjpeg turbo is for in memory manipulation of jpeg image data. ONLY.

Answer (score 1):

The main API files would be `jpeglib.h` and `jerror.h`. You can find these files as part of standard Android distribution also.`jpeglib.h` contains all the data structures, whereas `jerror.h` contains all error codes with corresponding messages.

Comment: A nice amount of comments in the header file too. Thx.