# Error handling in libjpeg

Tags: c++, libjpeg

I am using the C++ JPEG library (libjpeg) and I have realized that when some functions fail **exit()** is called and the application is closed. How can I override this behavior and prevent the application from closing on libjpeg errors?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is the default behavior of `libjpeg`. In order to handle errors with libjpeg, you'll have to define an error handling routine like this:

```
struct jpegErrorManager {
    /* "public" fields */
    struct jpeg_error_mgr pub;
    /* for return to caller */
    jmp_buf setjmp_buffer;
};
char jpegLastErrorMsg[JMSG_LENGTH_MAX];
void jpegErrorExit (j_common_ptr cinfo)
{
    /* cinfo->err actually points to a jpegErrorManager struct */
    jpegErrorManager* myerr = (jpegErrorManager*) cinfo->err;
    /* note : *(cinfo->err) is now equivalent to myerr->pub */

    /* output_message is a method to print an error message */
    /*(* (cinfo->err->output_message) ) (cinfo);*/      
    
    /* Create the message */
    ( *(cinfo->err->format_message) ) (cinfo, jpegLastErrorMsg);

    /* Jump to the setjmp point */
    longjmp(myerr->setjmp_buffer, 1);
  
}
```

And then register it using `jpeg_std_error`.

```
FILE* fileHandler;
/* ... */
struct jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo;
jpegErrorManager jerr;
cinfo.err = jpeg_std_error(&jerr.pub);
jerr.pub.error_exit = jpegErrorExit;
/* Establish the setjmp return context for my_error_exit to use. */
if (setjmp(jerr.setjmp_buffer)) {
    /* If we get here, the JPEG code has signaled an error. */
    cerr << jpegLastErrorMsg << endl;
    jpeg_destroy_decompress(&cinfo);
    fclose(fileHandler);
    return 1;
}
```

You can find a complete example [here](https://github.com/eiimage/detiq-t/blob/master/ImageIn/JpgImage.cpp).

Comment: Thank you so much, let me try it and I'll tell you :)

Comment: Wow, I didn't not about that jump mechanisms. Thank you so much, it worked!

Comment: You can try C++ lambda's with exceptions to create the exception handler inline -- see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/34351005/1151329

Comment: How do I trigger a JPEG error to make sure this function works? Preferably in the compressor.

Comment: @philix Load a Motion Panorama from a Samsung Galaxy. They're f*cked. :D

Answer (score 13):

As the question was targetting C++, an alternative approach with exceptions:

Error handler:

```
void jpegErrorExit ( j_common_ptr cinfo )
{
    char jpegLastErrorMsg[JMSG_LENGTH_MAX];
    /* Create the message */
    ( *( cinfo->err->format_message ) ) ( cinfo, jpegLastErrorMsg );

    /* Jump to the setjmp point */
    throw std::runtime_error( jpegLastErrorMsg ); // or your preffered exception ...
}
```

Use it:

```
FILE* fileHandler;
/* ... */
struct jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo;
struct jpeg_error_mgr jerr;
cinfo.err = jpeg_std_error( &jerr );
jerr.error_exit = jpegErrorExit;
try {
    jpeg_create_decompress( &cinfo );
    jpeg_stdio_src( &cinfo, fileHandler );
    /// ...
    jpeg_destroy_decompress( &cinfo );
    fclose( fileHandler );
}
catch ( std::runtime_exception & e ) {
    jpeg_destroy_decompress( &cinfo );
    fclose( fileHandler );
    throw; // or return an error code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think that is interesting to note that C++ does not mean that we should use exceptions. In fact, the Google C++ coding style says "We do not use exceptions" and no more :-)

Comment: I agree, it doesn't mean you should, I just means you can. 

Furthermore: basically jumps can cause the same potential issues as exceptions do, are typically not well known to C++ programmers plus even bare further risks: they can easily mess up with your RAII.
From www.cplusplus.com: "In C++, the implementation may perform stack unwinding that destroys objects with automatic duration. If this invokes any non-trivial destructors, it causes undefined behavior."

And Google styling guides btw also mentions that there are exceptions for all those rules, especially when libaries are used.

Comment: But libjpeg is C, not C++, so it has no destructors, nontrivial or otherwise, that setjmp/longjmp would tangle with.

Comment: If the code **calling** libjpeg is C++, all kind of resources could be created using RAII within the code calling libjpeg.

Answer (score 6):

Using c++11 I implemented this using a lambda (similar to Marco's answer):

```
[](j_common_ptr cinfo){throw cinfo->err;}
```

which works well.
Only then catch on 'struct jpeg_error_mgr *err'

i.e.

```
struct jpeg_error_mgr jerr_mgr;
cinfo.err = jpeg_std_error(&jerr_mgr);
jerr_mgr.error_exit = [](j_common_ptr cinfo){throw cinfo->err;};
```

and

```
   try
   {
      jpeg_create_decompress(&cinfo);

      ...
   }
   catch (struct jpeg_error_mgr *err)
    {
        char pszErr[1024];
        (cinfo.err->format_message)((j_common_ptr)&cinfo, pszErr);

         ...
    }
```

Comment: Is a ptr to a lambda guaranteed to work? jpeglib is a C library -- if the lambda is not strictly a block of code (e.g., some other callable object that the compiler generates), then the unerlying C code will fail.

Comment: Throwing exception through C code is tricky: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50069615/throwing-c-exception-through-c-function-call